# How to change background Color to MaterialButton from android.support.design programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I try change color to MaterialButton with this code:

```
var materialButton = findViewByid(R.id....) as MaterialButton
materialButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myCustomColor));
```

With a normal Button, it works.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It works with `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03` at least.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found the answer which is as below:

I changed the following line

```
materialButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myCustomColor));
```

to

```
materialButton.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this@MyActivity, R.color.myCustomColor));
```

I tested it that way and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Is it really correct ? `setBackgroundTintList = ... ` ?

Comment: This is not working for me. Is there any other way around?

Comment: This removes the ripple effect from the button

Answer (score 18):

Simply call this attribute in the XML file within Material Button.

```
 android:backgroundTint=""
```

Answer (score 8):

Lets try this:

```
mButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.indian_red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Does this solve the issue? Please also add explanation.

Comment: worked for me, though an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: this must be the Correct answer!

Comment: it works as i wanted.the concept of `Background Color` in android is not same with what i think. Very weird.

Comment: I get the following error with this code: Type mismatch.
Required: ColorFilter? Found: Int

Answer (score 2):

You should change your colorAccent to change background for your materialButton.

Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

For filled buttons, this class uses your theme's ?attr/colorAccent for the background tint color and white for the text color. For unfilled buttons, this class uses ?attr/colorAccent for the text color and transparent for the background tint.

Comment: I can´t change colorAccent beacause it change others components and views that use that color.
Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

materialButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myCustomColor));

Answer (score 0):

`materialButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this@MyActivity, R.color.myCustomColor))`

Working with material design dependency
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'`

Answer (score 0):

For C#/Xamarin.Android:

```
button.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.Color.ToAndroid());
```

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/extended_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/button" />
```

Java

```
 int integerValue = 0XFFC0C0C0;
 extendedBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(backgroundTint));
```

Kotlin

```
val integerValue = 0x00000000;
button.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(altColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I think it's best to handle all of the Views, but sadly here for MaterialButton it's different, so this is what I have for both:

```
fun View.setBackgroundTintColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    val background = background
    if (background is RippleDrawable) {
        val newBackground = background.mutate() as RippleDrawable
        if (color != 0)
            newBackground.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
        this.background = newBackground
    } else {
        if (color == 0)
            ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, null)
        else
            ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
    }
}

fun MaterialButton.setBackgroundTintColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(mButton.getBackground());
drawable.mutate();
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
```